# Scale down a number relative to a max number

Tags: math

So I've got a little thing that I'd like to do, but not sure how the maths would really work, it is not my strongest side. I'd like to scale down a number (n) to be below a max number (m). For example:

n = 120, m = 80. Requirement: 120 scaled down s it is relative to the maximum of 80. The minimum number being 0.

Is this something that can be mathematically done or do I change my model. I'm looking for a mathematical way to do it so I can translate it into code

Comment: You can "scale" it down to anything you want by multiplying by a scale factor. You'll need to provide more information for someone to know what makes sense in your project.

Comment: For a given m, say 80, what values can n have? What is the minimum, what is the maximum? Do you need to be able to recover m by reverse scaling later? Do you need to recover it exactly or just approximately? Are the values for m mostly uniformly distributed, like 0, 10, 20, 30… 120, or do they have some other distribution, like 1, 20, 100, 3000, 25000, …? Why do you want to do this; what purposes does it need to serve?

Comment: So for the example given, *n* could be let's say anything from 0 to 200, while *m* would be a multiple of lets say 10, recovery is not required as something like this will be passed onto a user-interface and used as a value for some finicky UI code and not required again.